# Can you implement SSML globally in Dialogflow?

Tags: dialogflow-es, ssml

Is there a way to implement a SSML elements to all your intents within a Dialogflow agent? More specifically, I want to add a prosody rate of 108% globally but I don't want to have to go through 5 pages of intents and follow-up intents manually adding the tag to every response. Thanks to anyone who can help.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using a fulfillment webhook you could write a function to add SSML tags to all responses. Please note that the SSML specification only requires the `speed` attribute work on recorded files (and does not require it work on text to speech voice engines): https://www.w3.org/TR/speech-synthesis11/#S3.3.1.3

On the Google Assistant the following should work with TTS:

```
<speak>
      <prosody speed="108%">This is being said at 108% speed.</prosody>
</speak>
```

which means your code should look something like:

```
ssmlResponse = '<speak><prosody speed="108%">' + response + '</prosody></speak>'
```

Dialogflow Fulfillment docs: https://dialogflow.com/docs/fulfillment

Comment: Thanks for the answer but with this method wouldn't you need to enable webhook fulfillment for every single intent?